# Why initialize the jQuery in $.ajax() success when adding fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using a jQuery datepicker on `.datepickerTime` and `.datePickerDate` classes.

```
$('.datepickerTime').datetimepicker({
    'timepicker': false,
    'mask': false,
    'format': 'M d,Y',
    'minDate': 0,
    'scrollMonth': false,
    'scrollInput': false,
    'allowTimes': [ '00:00','00:30','01:00','01:30','02:00','02:30','03:00','03:30','04:00','04:30','05:00','05:30','06:00','06:30','07:00','07:30','08:00','08:30','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:00','21:30','22:00','22:30','23:00','23:30' ]
});
```

When the page is loaded all datepickers work on the basis of classes. But when I added new field to my form having the datepicker class, then date picker does not work on it.

I have got the solution that I have to initialize the jquery again with ajax success .

I am confused why we need to initialize datepicker on AJAX success as we already have that jQuery on our page?

I am new to jquery and want to correct my basic concepts :-) , Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're adding a new element to the page then you need to initialise the datepicker on that new element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `re-initialize` your `datepicker` on `ajax-success` because the `element` will be added to `DOM` after you have initialized the `plugin`. You will have 2 options here.

- Either re-initialize inside `ajax-success`
  or
- Initialize it on `document` or `body` or any `element` which will be parent of your `datepicker` element and which will be there on initial `DOM` load.

For your 2nd method, below is the

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepickerTime", function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
       'timepicker': false,
       'mask': false,
       'format': 'M d,Y',
       'minDate': 0,
       'scrollMonth': false,
       'scrollInput': false,
       'allowTimes': [ '00:00','00:30','01:00','01:30','02:00','02:30','03:00','03:30','04:00','04:30','05:00','05:30','06:00','06:30','07:00','07:30','08:00','08:30','09:00','09:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30','12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30','16:00','16:30','17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:00','21:30','22:00','22:30','23:00','23:30' ]
   });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

you should add new class or id for new element and call datetimepicker for your  new element to init